# Rails jquery sortable list not saving

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, jquery-ui-sortable

Sorting the list with javascript works fine, however when I refresh the page, the sorted list returns to its original position rather than saving. Looks like the POST request does not seem to be working.

My controller

```
  class SlidesController < ApplicationController
  before_filter :authenticate_user!

    def index
    @slides = Slide.all

    respond_to do |format|
    format.html # index.html.erb
    format.json { render json: @slides }
    end
  end

    def sort
      @slides = slide.all
      @slides.each do |slide|
      slide.position = params['slide'].index(slide.id.to_s) + 1
      slide.save
      end
    end

      def create
    @status = Status.find(params[:status_id])
    @slide = @status.slides.create(params[:slide])
       respond_to do |format|
      if @slide.save
        format.html { redirect_to (status_path(@status, :anchor => "form")) }
        format.json { render json: @status, slide: :created, location: @status }
      else
format.html { redirect_to @status, alert: 'Contents of slide must be between 1 - 200 characters long.' }
        format.json { render json: @slide.errors, slide: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
   end

      def destroy
    @status = Status.find(params[:status_id])
    @slide = @status.slides.find(params[:id])
    @slide.destroy
    redirect_to status_path(@status)
  end

  def edit
    @status = Status.find(params[:status_id])
    @slide = @status.slides.find(params[:id])
  end

def update
    @status = Status.find(params[:status_id])
    @slide = @status.slides.find(params[:id])
    @slide.update_attributes(params[:slide])
    redirect_to (status_path(@status, :anchor => "slide_#{(@slide.id)}"))
  end

end
```

Sorting the list javascript

```
    $(document).ready(function () {
    $('#slides').sortable({
        axis : 'y',
        dropOnEmpty : false,
        handle : '.handle',
        cursor : 'crosshair',
        items : 'li',
        opacity : 0.4,
        scroll : true,
        update : function () {
            $.ajax({
                type : 'POST',
                beforeSend : function (xhr) {
                    xhr.setRequestHeader('X-CSRF-Token', $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content'))
                },
                data : $('#slides').sortable('serialize'),
                dataType : 'script',
                complete : function (request) {
                    $('#slides').effect('highlight');
                },
                url : '/statuses'
            })
        }
    });
});
```

Slide model

```
 class Slide < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :content
  belongs_to :status

  validates :content, presence: true, length: { minimum: 1, maximum: 200 }
  acts_as_list
end
```

Comment: I know this is an old question, but what version of rails are you using?